# linux - Play sound on login?

Tags: linux, bashrc, job-control

I've installed Gentoo without a GUI and have appended `aplay /usr/shar/sounds/startup3.wav &> /dev/null &` to my /etc/bash/bashrc file. This works just fine in playing the sound file, but once the sound finishes and I hit enter, it tells me the process has finished. When I make the sound play in the foreground, I don't have the ability to do anything in my terminal until the sound is done playing.

Is there any way I can play the sound without any output or disruption after logging in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That "Done" message is because the shell has the command still under its job control:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 660
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 10 &

 (time passes)

$ 
[1]+  Done                    sleep 10
```

You can simply remove all jobs from job control with `disown`<sup>(a)</sup>

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 3804
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
$ disown
$ jobs
$
```

I don't know a method to disown a job right with its start<sup>(b)</sup>, so I propose that you simply put a `disown` to your bashrc, right after the sound command. However this will disown all jobs -- I don't know if this is wanted. Otherwise you can use `disown %aplay`.

---

(a) `man bash`

> **disown [-ar] [-h] [jobspec ...]**
>                 Without options, each jobspec is removed from the table of active jobs.  If jobspec is not present, and neither -a nor -r
>                 is supplied, the shell's notion of the current job is used.  If the -h option is given, each jobspec is not removed  from
>                 the table, but is marked so that SIGHUP is not sent to the job if the shell receives a SIGHUP.  If no jobspec is present,
>                 and neither the -a nor the -r option is supplied, the current job is used.  If no jobspec  is  supplied,  the  -a  option
>                 means  to  remove  or  mark  all jobs; the -r option without a jobspec argument restricts operation to running jobs.  The
>                 return value is 0 unless a jobspec does not specify a valid job.

(b) However, in the Z Shell `zsh`this is easy:

```
zsh$ sleep 10 &!
zsh$ jobs
zsh$
```

Comment: In bash, `(sleep 10 &)` is a frequently used workaround. `setsid sleep 10` is another, depending on the requirements (it's different from `&` in that it also detaches from the controlling tty).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I ended up doing `(command &)` from the comment above, but disown is good to know about, as well as `&!` in zsh.